# Converting a future to a stream in kube-rs library

Tags: rust, stream, future

I'm trying to implement a project where I can tail the logs of multiple Kubernetes container logs simultaneously. Think tmux split pane with two tails in each pane. Anyway, I'm far far away from my actual project because I'm stuck right at the beginning. If you look at the following code then the commented out line for lp.follow = true will keep the log stream open and stream logs forever. I'm not sure how to actually use this. I found a function called `.into_stream()` that I can tack onto the pods.log function, but then I'm not sure how to actually use the stream. I'm not experienced enough to know if this is a limitation of the kube library, or if I'm just doing something wrong. Anyway, here is the repo if you want to look at anything else. https://github.com/bloveless/kube-logger

I'd be forever grateful for any advice or resources I can look at. Thanks!

```
use kube::{
    api::Api,
    client::APIClient,
    config,
};
use kube::api::{LogParams, RawApi};
use futures::{FutureExt, Stream, future::IntoStream, StreamExt};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    std::env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "info,kube=trace");
    let config = config::load_kube_config().await?;
    let client = APIClient::new(config);

    // Manage pods
    let pods = Api::v1Pod(client).within("fritzandandre");
    let mut lp = LogParams::default();
    lp.container = Some("php".to_string());
// lp.follow = true;
    lp.tail_lines = Some(100);

    let log_string = pods.log("fritzandandre-php-0", &lp).await?;
    println!("FnA Log: {}", log_string);

    Ok(())
}
```

Originally posted here https://www.reddit.com/r/learnrust/comments/eg49tx/help_with_futuresstreams_and_the_kubers_library/